# Large list issue with CSOM

Tags: list, client-object-model, list-view

Let's say there is a list with very large number of records. Now applying a particular filter on a list also retrieves very large number of items, more than threshold value. Retrieving list item is creating performance issue. Now, server side code is not permitted, only client side code is permitted. How to tackle this issue? What steps should be taken?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use CAML queries. These queries are executed in the server and will retrieve only the items requested for.

Use Pagination to iterate through the items. For that you can use `ListItemCollectionPosition`

Here is a snippet you are use for this

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("weburl");
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListTitle");
ListItemCollectionPosition position = null;
do
{
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
    camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View>
                            <ViewFields>
                              <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                            </ViewFields>
                            <RowLimit>5000</RowLimit>
                          </View>";
    ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    position = listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
    foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", listItem["Title"]);
}
while(position != null)
```

Comment: Yes this solution is working.. but if we add <Query></Query> and use non index column.. It's not working.. have any solution for this?

Comment: Depends on your requirements !
What you have to do ?

Comment: @SID non index column will not work in the caml query, in case if you need to include those columns, you will have to index those columns

Comment: @SID maximum of 20 columns can be indexed