# Fetching and displaying more than 5000 list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, splistitem, sharepoint-hosted-app, list-view-threshold

I am aware of the list items threshold of 5000 items. But I need to display more than 5000 items on a SharePoint Hosted Addin and on a .net website.

How can I overcome this constraint? Also, I do wish to achieve this goal without compromising on the performance issues.

Any suggestion for the same would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried indexing of column(s) in list? Use indexed column in Add-in to fetch the data.

Answer (score 3):

The 5000 items threshold, restricts the number of items you can fetch using one query/view. You can read more than 5000 items by fetching the items in batches or provide pagination.

Here is another thread which has the CSOM code snippet to read list items in batches - [Large list issue with CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128373/large-list-issue-with-csom)