# fetch more than 5000 items from sharepoint list view in sharepoint online and export it to the CSV File

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

we have requirement to fetch more than 5000 items from the sharepoint list and export it to csv file using csom / Rest Api

how we can achieve this?

any guidance

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the 5000 item limit you will need to use Batch CAML queries in CSOM and then paginate by using the `ListItemCollectionPosition` property.

You can refer to code example at this link [Large list issue with CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128373/large-list-issue-with-csom)

Answer (score 0):

You could create indexed column and then use the indexed column in CSOM CAML Query and then use this CSOM Script to export items to CSV:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SharePoint.Client') | Out-Null

$login = 'test@test.onmicrosoft.com'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$webUrl = 'https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/'
$listName = 'My List'

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext $webUrl
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials $login, $password

$web = $context.Web
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$items = $list.GetItems($query)

$context.Load($items)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$items | Select @{ L = "Title"; E = { $_["Title"] } }, @{ L = "Created"; E = { $_["Created"] } } | Export-Csv -Path export.csv
```

[Overcoming the List View Threshold in SharePoint CAML queries](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1076854/Overcoming-the-List-View-Threshold-in-SharePoint-C)